# Is it possible to boot an x86 Linux kernel using both 80x25 text mode consoles and VESA framebuffer consoles?

Tags: linux, terminal, boot

The Linux kernel documents that you can choose to boot Linux with VESA framebuffer consoles instead of the default 80x25 text mode consoles.

For text application testing purposes, one may need both modes simultaneously. For instance, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> in 80x25 text mode and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> in framebuffer mode.

Is there a way to achieve dual mode text displays in a single boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you boot the kernel in text mode (standard on x86), you can change the VESA mode after boot with `vbetool`, using the `vbemode` action.

If you boot the kernel in framebuffer mode (standard on non-x86), you can change the resolution at runtime with `fbset`.

When you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, etc., the kernel probably sends `SIGWINCH` to the `INIT` process (pid 1). The default `init` program probably generates a `kbrequest` event, you may be able to pick up on that by modifying `/etc/inittab` and have `init` run a script that sets the mode for you.